# Windows Store App/game getting 0x80240017 error during download/installation

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I've got a UWP game in the Microsoft Store. The majority of people that have installed it have not reported any issues. However, 2 people have now reported getting error 0x80240017 during the installation process.

I've been doing a lot of research on the subject, but I can't find anything that is particularly helpful. The error often seems to be connected to the Windows Update process.

Any insights that I can provide to my users would be appreciated. I'd also like some idea why this error is happening, in case there is something I can do from the developer's side of things to prevent it from happening in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: Have those customers try the steps in [KB4027498](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/microsoft-store-fix-problems-with-apps) to make sure it's not a system issue.

Comment: If the two customers are running Windows 8/8.1, could  they try the following step?[Run the computer as administrator / Press Win+R/ type wsreset.exe/Click OK]

Comment: The customers are using Windows 10.  I don't know what build they're on.

Comment: I'll pass on the link to the KB article.  Thanks.  (PS.  I couldn't get into the Store support page yesterday or today while using Edge.  I switched over to Chrome and I got in fine.  It seems the Support pages don't like Edge.)

Comment: Sometimes this issue fixed by clearing and resetting Windows Store cache .[Step:Restart computer and log in admin account > press Windows + R >type WSReset.exe >restart system and login in again]

Comment: I have heard back from one of the users.  He has tried both the info from the article as well as resetting the windows store cache.  Same error.  He's running version 10.0.18363, which is higher than my game's required build version.

Comment: The aforementioned user is actually getting a different error code: x803fb005